# Cannot save into file system an image encoded in base64

Tags: php, android, image, base64

I'm uploading an image from Android to a PHP server. In android I'm encoding the bitmap image as a base64 string:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(DatosDB.KEY_IMG, Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT)));
```

I've tried printing the resulting String and it does look like an encoded image. This is it:

```
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
```

And then, on the server side, this is the chunk of PHP that is supposed to decode that String and save it in the File System:

```
function base64_decode_image($image, $name){
    if ($image){
        $new_file = fopen("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/img/" . $name, "x");
        fwrite($new_file, base64_decode($image));
        fclose($new_file);
        //echo base64_decode($image);
    }
}
```

I've also tried with this:

```
    $decoded = base64_decode($image);
    file_put_contents("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/api/img/" . $name, $decoded);
```

But no change. It saves the image but I cannot visualize it. I checked that the String that I'm receiving as an image in PHP is the same one that was sent from Android, and the name of the file is also right.

So what am I missing here? Is the error on the Android side or on the server side?

Comment: You could add your base64 encoded data, so it's easier to follow where the problem occurs.

Comment: For an issue like this you can actually try to decode using base64 to an image and make sure you can actually see an image first even before making a post to the server and making a wild guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly a typo:

```
file_put_contents("/Appications/MAMP/htdocs/api/img/" . $name . ".jpg", $decoded);
                       ^-- missing an L?
```

As well, check that you actually ARE getting base64-encoded data from Android. It's simple enough to do a `var_dump($image)` and see if you base64 data echoed out.

Comment: You're absolutely right, what a morron am I! Now the file is created but I cannot visualize it. I'm gonna edit the question to show the encoded String.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user running your PHP server actually have the rights to write to that directory?  PHP will sometimes silently fail at writing the image.